# Firebase Cloud Database Trigger Functions not always completing

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a database triggered function, that triggers when a team administrator adds new members to his team. The function is supposed to create authentication in Firebase and an object, where the new user can store his personal settings.
My problem is, that when a lot of members are added simultaneously via an import feature, my function doesn't always complete. Since they seem to be triggered alright when I look at the log, I suspect my implementation of chained promises to be the error cause. Here is a copy of the code. Please help me correct the errors.

```
// When a team adds a new member, we should also create authentication and a record for his user data...
exports.createNewUserAndAuthOnNewMember = functions
  .database
  .ref('/Members/{team}/{memberId}/createNewUser')
  .onCreate(event => {

  const memberRef = admin.database().ref('/Members/'+event.params.team+'/'+event.params.memberId);

  memberRef.once('value')
  .then((memberSnap) => {
    const memberEmail = memberSnap.child('email').val();
    const preferredLanguage = memberSnap.child('preferredLanguage').val();

    // Creating authentication for new system user...
    //since we want to update the /user object later on even if the authentication creation fails (because user already exists), this promise is inside the top promise chain
    admin.auth().createUser({
      uid: event.params.memberId,
      email: memberEmail,
      emailVerified: false,
      password: '[random password generated]',
      disabled: false
    })
    .then(function(userRecord) {
      console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
      return preferredLanguage;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
      return preferredLanguage;
    });

  })
  .then(preferredLanguage => {
    // Creating the personal user object in the database
    admin.database().ref('/users/'+event.params.memberId).update({'team': event.params.team, 'preferredLanguage': preferredLanguage});
  })
  .then(() => {
    //we did the job and should remove the trigger from the member object in the database
    memberRef.child('createNewUser').remove();
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Created /users/'+event.params.memberId);
    return true;    
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
exports.createNewUserAndAuthOnNewMember = functions
    .database
    .ref('/Members/{team}/{memberId}/createNewUser')
    .onCreate(event => {

        let preferredLanguage;

        const memberRef = admin.database().ref('/Members/' + event.params.team + '/' + event.params.memberId);

        return memberRef.once('value')
            .then((memberSnap) => {
                const memberEmail = memberSnap.child('email').val();
                preferredLanguage = memberSnap.child('preferredLanguage').val();

                // Creating authentication for new system user...
                //since we want to update the /user object later on even if the authentication creation fails (because user already exists), this promise is inside the top promise chain
                return admin.auth().createUser({
                    uid: event.params.memberId,
                    email: memberEmail,
                    emailVerified: false,
                    password: '[random password generated]',
                    disabled: false
                })
            })
            .then(() => {
                // Creating the personal user object in the database
                return admin.database().ref('/users/' + event.params.memberId).update({'team': event.params.team, 'preferredLanguage': preferredLanguage});
            })
            .then(() => {
                //we did the job and should remove the trigger from the member object in the database
                return memberRef.child('createNewUser').remove();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                //...
            });
    });
```

You have to return the promise in each `then()` when chaining them, and you only need one catch at the end of the chain.

---

In addition, note that you are using the "old" syntax for Cloud Functions. Since version 1.0.+ there is a new syntax, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Comment: Thanks @renaud 
It makes sense. I was unsure if the database functions should have "return " prefixed or if this unnecessary. With your changes, all work except the error is thrown if the user already exists. I have added a .then() and a .catch() to the admin.auth().createUser() function so it handles its own promise inside the chain. Then it seems to be the correct solution. (and yes I haven't updated to the new Cloud Functions syntax yet).

Comment: @SimonKibsgård Accept the answer, please

Comment: @SimonKibsgård I am not sure it is a good idea to add a specific catch() to the admin.auth().createUser() function. Better catch this error in the existing ending catch at the end of the chain and find a way to identify (from the error object returned) that the error comes from this method. If such an error is generated by the admin.auth().createUser() function  the following when()s will not be executed.

Comment: @renaud, I agree, but in my case I didn't see it as an error if the user auth existed. It would of course be more elegant if I just did a preliminary check before trying to create the user